# wavesurfer.js : record audio and upload to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vuejs2, upload, wavesurfer.js

I'm using the wavesurfer.js library and its record plugin for a vuejs project. I'm using the record plugin to create a voice message.

I would like to be able to retrieve the blob of the audio file and upload it to my Amazon S3 server.

After a lot of research, I've managed to create this code, but I can't figure out how I can retrieve the audio file created by the record plugin and upload it to the server.

What do I need to do?

```
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
import RecordPlugin from 'wavesurfer.js/dist/plugins/record';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      audioUrl: ''
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initializeWaveSurfer()
  },
  methods: {
    initializeWaveSurfer() {
      this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#visualizer',
        barWidth: 3,
        barHeight: 1.5,
        cursorWidth: 0,
        height: 46,
        responsive: true,
        waveColor: 'rgba(108,115,202,0.3)',
        cursorColor: 'transparent',
      })

      this.record = this.wavesurfer.registerPlugin(RecordPlugin.create());
    },
    startRecording() {
      this.isRecording = true
      this.record.startRecording();
    },
    stopRecording() {
      this.isRecording = false
      this.record.stopRecording();
      this.uploadAudio(*blob*) // Need tu upload here
    },
    uploadAudio(blob) {
      const s3 = new AWS.S3({
        accessKeyId: 'xxxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxxx',
        region: 'xxxx'
      })

      const params = {
        Bucket: 'xxxx',
        Key: 'test.webm',
        Body: blob,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: 'audio/webm'
      }

      s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error uploading audio:', err)
        } else {
          console.log('Audio uploaded successfully:', data)
        }
      })
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT 11/07/2023 09:00 (GMT+1)**

I tried this... apparently wavesurfer.js returns a URL in blob format. I then injected it into the upload but the webm file generated doesn't contain the audio stream: it contains the blob's text-format url.

```
stopRecording() {
      this.isRecording = false
      this.record.stopRecording();

      this.record.on('stopRecording', () => {
        this.uploadAudio(this.record.getRecordedUrl());
      });
    },
```

I then tried to transform the content into a binary, but I couldn't generate the audio file (it wouldn't play).

```
stopRecording() {
      this.isRecording = false
      this.record.stopRecording();

      this.record.on('stopRecording', () => {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', this.record.getRecordedUrl(), true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';

        xhr.onload = function (e) {
          if (this.status === 200)
          {
            var blob = this.response;
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function () {
              var fileData = reader.result;
              this.uploadAudio(fileData); // Not Working
            };
            
            reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
          }
        };

        xhr.send();
      });

    }
```

I'd be really happy if we could help him. I'm new to vuejs: I started last night.

Thanks

Comment: Might help: [How to export WaveSurfer js as audio file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62260599/174777)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I implemented bufferToWave but how i can access the buffer ? this.record.buffer || this.record.backend.buffer || app.engine.wavesurfer.backend.buffer || this.wavesurfer.backend.buffer doesn't work

Comment: Using "wavesurfer.js": "^7.0.0"